# Failed to execute 'appendChild' error when appending text content to items in list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add text items to a list from an array of values held in an object.

My JS looks like this -

```
var MiFiveLog = function(person) {                        

    var ul = document.querySelector('.logged-interactions-list');

    for (i = 0; i < person.loggedMessages.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(person.loggedMessages[i]);
        ul.appendChild(textNode);
    }
}
```

Person constructor -

```
Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name,
    this.loggedMessages = []
}
```

Looks simple enough but the script is giving me the following console error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Bit confused - would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code. What is `person`? And, more importantly, what is `person.loggedMessages[i]` because, clearly that is not a `node` and that is why it can't be appended. Please add enough code to show a working example that produces the error you are getting.

Comment: Why are you creating an `li` element and not doing anything with it?

Comment: Also, you should be appending `textNode` to `li` first and then appending `li` to `ul`.  Additionally, you don't even have to go through the trouble of explicitly creating a new `textNode`. You can just write `li.textContent = person.loggedMessages[i]`.

Comment: This won't solve the problem but I think your goal is to append the `textNode` to the `li` element and then append `li` to the `ul` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, but you haven't shown us what your `person` object looks like, so that is most likely the culprit. If you look at my sample below, you'll see the structure that the object needs to be set up with in order to use the syntax: `person.loggedMessages[i]` in a loop.

Also, you should be appending your text nodes to the list items, not the list and then the list items should be appended to the list.

Finally, you can skip the explicit construction of a text node (if you like) and just use the `textContent` property.

See comments below:

```js
// Here's your object structure, which is OK, but you have to instantiate it
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name,
    this.loggedMessages = []
}

// Instantiate the object and populate the array property:
var p2 = new Person("John Doe");
p2.loggedMessages.push("message 1");
p2.loggedMessages.push("message 2");
p2.loggedMessages.push("message 3");
p2.loggedMessages.push("message 4");

var MiFiveLog = function(person) {                        

    var ul = document.querySelector('.logged-interactions-list');

    for (i = 0; i < person.loggedMessages.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        
        // You can accomplish this the way you were attempting except that the
        // text nodes should be appended to the list items, not the list:
        //var textNode = document.createTextNode(person.loggedMessages[i]);
        //li.appendChild(textNode);  
        
        // Or, you can skip the text node and appending it to the list item completely
        // and just insert the text into the list item:
        li.textContent = person.loggedMessages[i]
        
        ul.appendChild(li);  // The list items should be appended to the unordered list
    }
}

MiFiveLog(p2);  // Invoke the function and pass it the instance
```

```html
<ul class="logged-interactions-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. it's look like my Person constructor is at fault - i'm just not sure where the problem is I can add messages in to loggedMessages and query them through the console. 

If I copy and paste your for loop in to my code it still doesn't work (even though it does when I run the code snippet above) so again i'd assume my Person object is at fault.

I've included the code with my original question.

Comment: @JonK Please show the code where you actually instantiate a `Person` and populate its properties.

Comment: @JonK I've updated my answer to show your constructor code being instantiated into an object instance and configured.

Comment: Cheers Scott - I've got it working now based on your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonK Could you post a comment to let us know what the issue wound up being? This will help others who read this in the future.